# When have have I to use var before a variable name in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I know that in JavaScript I can define a variable in this way:

```
menuItems = new Array();
```

or putting the **var** before the variable name, so:

```
var menuItems = new Array();
```

Exist some difference between these two versions ? What change?

Tnx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you don't use var it goes into the global scope (in browser into the window object, in node into the global object). So your first one is equivalent to `window.menuItems = ...` in a browser.

This is not usually good because you are polluting the window object potentially overwriting or leaving menuItems to be overwritten by other code.

---

In the 2nd case it goes into a variable that exists in the scope of the function that wraps that bit of code and any other functions inside it. So

```
...

function() {
    ... bits of code except creation of a function ...
    var menuItems = new Array();
    ... bits of code ...
}

// menuItems is undefined here so whatever you do on something called menuItems here actually acts on a different variable menuItems
```

---

http://speakingjs.com/es5/ch16.html is an excellent link if you want to delve into details.